# Unknown model type "level" -- ignored Fatal Error: Unknown SPICE device type "Ï" in "ï»¿"

Tags: ltspice

I have been trying to use LTspice XVII with a model from Dr Lynn Fuller https://people.rit.edu/lffeee/CD4007_SPICE_MODEL.pdf.

However I get the error messages 
Unknown model type "level" -- ignored 
Fatal Error: Unknown SPICE device type "Ï" in "ï»¿"

Here's the model (I've tried changing LEVEL=7 to 8)

```
.MODEL CD4007_Nchan (LEVEL=7
+VERSION=3.1 CAPMOD=2 MOBMOD=1
+TOX=4E-8 XJ=2.9E-7 NCH=4E15 NSUB=5.33E15 XT=8.66E-8
+VTH0=1.4 U0= 1300 WINT=2.0E-7 LINT=1E-7
+NGATE=5E20 RSH=300 JS=3.23E-8 JSW=3.23E-8 CJ=6.8E-8 MJ=0.5 PB=0.95
+CJSW=1.26E-10 MJSW=0.5 PBSW=0.95 PCLM=5
+CGSO=3.4E-10 CGDO=3.4E-10 CGBO=5.75E-10)
```

Comment: That "unknown SPICE device type" message makes me wonder if something fell apart character-encoding-wise...

Comment: Yeah, if you copy/pasted from a PDF you might want to look at it/clean it up in a text editor before using it.

Comment: Looks like the first of the two 4007 models here: https://people.rit.edu/lffeee/RIT_Models_For_LTSPICE.txt

Comment: It looks like a UTF-8 BOM (completely useless byte order mark) read as ISO 8859-1.  You should resave the file with a decent text editor.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments:

It looks like a UTF-8 BOM (completely useless byte order mark) read as ISO 8859-1. You should resave the file with a decent text editor.

Comment: Thanks guys you were right! I had used Notepad, which I thought was OK. I opened it in Wordpad and resaved it and it worked!

Comment: @PeterSeligman I'm glad it helps. Yet another example why people should _stop writing answers in the comments!_ Gah. How is that so difficult, there's a reminder every single time...